# Is there any event in monaco-editor for selecting an option from the list of suggestions?

Tags: javascript, documentation, monaco-editor

I need to respond to a user selecting any of the suggestions item coming from **registerCompletionProvider**. I can't seem to find any such event mentioned in the official documentation.
Monaco-editor version - 0.17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this by registering a [command](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/functions/editor.addCommand.html) which you then invoke via the [command](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/languages.CompletionItem.html#command) property on a [CompletionItem](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/languages.CompletionItem.html).

You can register the action (defining a callback function which you want to execute when the item is chosen):

```
// Register the callback function as a command
var commandId = editor.addCommand(
    -1,
    function (_, ...args) {
        // Callback that will be executed when the user selects option
        console.log('user selected:', args);
    },
    ""
);
```

Then configure the `completionProvider` as you normally would:

```
function createDependencyProposals(range) {
    // returning a static list of proposals, not even looking at the prefix (filtering is done by the Monaco editor),
    // here you could do a server side lookup
    return [
        {
            label: 'item 1',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "This is item 1.",
            insertText: 'item 1',
            range: range,
            command: {
                id: commandId, // ID of the command of the callback function
                title: "commandTitle",
                arguments: ['item 1']
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'item 2',
            kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Function,
            documentation: "This is item 2.",
            insertText: 'item 2',
            range: range,
            command: {
                id: commandId, // ID of the command of the callback function
                title: "commandTitle",
                arguments: ['item 2']
            }
        },
    ];
}

monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider("json", {
    provideCompletionItems: function (model, position) {
        var word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
        var range = {
            startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
            startColumn: word.startColumn,
            endColumn: word.endColumn,
        };
        return {
            suggestions: createDependencyProposals(range),
        };
    },
});
```

The important bit to note here is that each completion item defines a `command` property:

```
command: {
    id: commandId, // ID of the command of the callback function
    title: "commandTitle",
    arguments: ['item 2']
}
```

`id` is the ID of the command you registered that contains the callback function you want to execute when the user selects the suggestion. `arguments` can be whatever you want, but you will likely need to pass something that indicates which suggestion they've chosen, otherwise you won't be able to tell in the callback function.

There's a [working demo](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.17.1#XQAAAAJbBgAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw_UBDLRiWjvC21hSk_P0Wtqheo5czMcl6QDf7JKeFLedcvClW8aZjrxpWB6QyplUK2tHHC6GDlIPo7ShjSWXYY858nwRgCQRHkRWxK_QYzR_ul0b869pc00wmCNYBZEoB8r9Z9g-ijgtkIy1YWgJHgmE-UMPebein3ZHnNNQ70lU1rj7Mwb_wX1-WWjOvTaGDURmV3LLUKhS_L_5WUFQ6FZ8q3aMPaU26D9kkCdh20HKGqFcX0nUkceOgWOHmH-xXSYbg_qoCq3JKtepXEyPB-BIK4l_cReReMjT2YqfyyfFYO3Fjbr1MyrExELwFi0plT6YjByQ88qcjTzJOW25cLTtfmW3JsWZkMQ-1P3h6k54Hryxxoq9J5g1TgtQc8KxTXHQj_KeCmiBiePqAS0zPD7vH5uiWLuT07ujyPU30zynEcRsaVbv-Xv0h_FWk6kJNxLSPNSvrObz_l6EZbM2Y6_F8yoUpgm_s1Eell_qNCgpsTU_wD_LPTouqyVnvqsLqy5tyKwq9VrGDNYiVpyTjhPQJkeY-8YFVwtuzXLSP2P0_rm5gGf8847dWLqpPiZJMg4Y8FrejHNILruQmVGnUftuQR46eLlGYxY1_7rg_eruqUzSMoI6R7fD5FCZpvGJXUm626lzktA3KoflERRifMpAtrB5c_bTm50wR7a75_3VOnmv8BUMN6HbaJybjUP9fEtM2GENzgtoYzTqnYFsfs-ENhBN3Jv5xnG6PN7G00D8H9n9hqJpU3NdCwUWliemYV4f4LxMZQ78cschT2SLYcoI3FuLvdOxlVJ4U6ddLw9JgsNO2Q1U-QoDwKUetVO03hegMaDiaikJlUOBBvKepp3bbx8GNX38FKvAo1nZuN_yOilqRewYbxZ74YopfFmoL_3-tf8Y) of this (the demo uses the same version you mentioned in your question `0.17.1` but should also work on later versions of Monaco too). If you open the console tab of developer tools, then type the letter `i` and select an option, you should see something like this logged to the console:

> user selected: ["item 1"]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried using this earlier, it did trigger the command on selecting any suggestion but for some reason the "args" in the callback function inside commandId was undefined so I had to find a workaround for this. 
However, I tested your snippet on the playground, it seems to work absolutely fine, so accepting the solution.